# Searching among documents with roles associated

Tags: c#, sql-server, search, solr, elasticsearch

I have a huge database (sql server) of text documents (~ 500GB so far). I do full text search on them.

I want to use solr/elastic search for this purpose.

However, text documents are associated with roles in organization, ie: manager documents, or bosses' documents. And roles of people change now and then.

I dont have a problem writing a sql query for this purpose.

I can't think of doing the same with Solr/elastic search.

How would you solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a good blog post about this topic "[Custom security filtering in Solr](http://searchhub.org/2012/02/22/custom-security-filtering-in-solr/)". It shows how to implement the PostFilter Interface where you can do anything Java offers to check if a document maybe accessed or not. This is intended for the case that you have some remote system that holds the access information, like a corporate LDAP.

---

But as the author notes

> It’s important to note that PostFilter is a last resort for implementing document filtering.  Don’t make the solution more complicated than it needs to be.  More often than not, even access control filtering can be implemented using plain ol’ search techniques, by indexing allowed users and groups onto documents and using the lucene (or another) query parser to do the trick.  Only when the rules are too complicated, or external information is needed, does a custom PostFilter make sense.

That means: Would it not be possible to add fields to the documents that hold the access information? Something like

```xml
<fields>

    <!-- your other fields -->

    <field name="owner" 
        type="String" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
    <field name="team" 
        type="String" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
    <field name="team-lead" 
        type="String" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
    <field name="roles" 
        type="String" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />
</fields>
```

Then when searching you can add to the query

> q=some+cool+query&fq=owner:username+OR+team:user's team name+OR+role:role1